# Importing facebook sdk to android studio ruins my program

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I have updated android studio to 0.5.9 and i downloaded the latest facebook SDK .
My problem is that whenever i try to import Facebook sdk from file ->import module->"facebook SDK path" the support v4 library magically disapears from extrernal libraries and i cant import anything from it(activityBar,fragments etc).So why is this happening?Am i missing something?

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: i followed this guide from stackoverflow... If you're running the latest, all you need to do is this:

Download the Facebook SDK from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/
Unzip the archive
In Android Studio 0.5.5 or later, choose "Import Module" from the File menu.
In the wizard, set the source path of the module to import as the "facebook" directory inside the unpacked archive.

Comment: Is your project using Gradle 1.12, by any chance?

Comment: i use grandle 1.10. 1.12 doesnt seem to work.If i add classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+' to build.grandle i get error so i use 0.10 instead

Comment: ok i was confused about gradle and gradle plugin.I have build.gradle  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+' and gradle -wrapper.properties distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip.So i guees i am using the latest gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this while experimenting with test cases in response to this question and filed bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70825. We haven't found a root cause yet, but it seems only to happen if you're using Gradle 1.12.

Fortunately, there's a workaround, which is to switch to using Gradle 1.11 by setting the value in your **gradle-wrapper.properties** file:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

Comment: unfortunately,gradle 1.11 doesnt work for me.I just cant find the support library at external libraries...I am so confused here...i have also tried gradle 1.10 without luck

Comment: @martinseal1987 no i have no idea what's wrong with my android studio.
I tried to install android studio to my laptop instead but i have the same problem.